# Android requestFocus issue

Tags: android, focus, edit

I have a `ViewFlipper` with several `LinearLayout` with `EditText`s; after pressing a button, there's some validation done, and should it fail, I need to set the focus to the Edit that needs to be modified. `vf` is the `ViewFlipper`; `et123` is an `EditText`. When there's an error detected, the following is executed:

```
 vf.setDisplayedChild(5);
 findViewById(R.id.et123).requestFocus();
```

The funny thing is that the first time the button is pressed, the focus goes to another element in the right Layout. If I press the button one more time, the focus goes to `et123`.

Any ideas on why does it happen or how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might need to call

```
findViewById(R.id.et123).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Before calling `requestFocus()` to enable receiving focus.

Comment: It works for me, thank you. 
But I still don't understand why I should use it when I navigate for the app via D-Pad, it is not TouchMode.